# Combine Array with String

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to combine an array with a string.
But unfortunately it is not working like I want.

My code:

```
$split = -split $array
$mail = 'test_'
$domain = "@test.com"
ForEach-Object {$mail + $split + $domain}
```

**My Output looks like this:**

`test_2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100@test.com`

**What i need:**

```
test_2@test.com
test_3@test.com
test_4@test.com
test_5@test.com
test_6@test.com
test_7@test.com
test_8@test.com
test_9@test.com
test_10@test.com
...
```

Can someone help me with my problem?
Thank you!

Comment: `2..100 | ForEach-Object { "test_ " + $_ + "@test.com" }`.

Answer (score 3):

The [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet requires *pipeline input*, which you're not providing (in its absence, the script block is called *once*, which means there is no point in using `ForEach-Object` at all).

Also, since you need *per-element* processing of your `$split` array, you must *enumerate* it, which the pipeline does for you automatically, as [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert)'s comment implies:

```bash
# Enumerate the elements of array $split, i.e. send
# its elements one by one to ForEach-Object, which sees each as $_
# Note: You can capture the results in a variable simply by 
#       uncommenting the next line:
# $emailAddresses = 
$split | ForEach-Object { $mail + $_ + $domain }
```

Note the use of the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_), which refers to the current pipeline input object in each iteration.

---

However, with values already in memory it is more efficient to use the [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) *statement*:

```bash
# Note: You can capture the results in a variable simply by 
#       uncommenting the next line:
# $emailAddresses = 
foreach ($index in $split) { $mail + $index + $domain }
```

Note the need to specify the input as part of the `(...)` expression, and the need to name a self-chosen enumeration (iterator) variable.

---

Finally, a concise and efficient but somewhat obscure solution is to use the regex-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator:

```bash
# Note: You can capture the results in a variable simply by 
#       uncommenting the next line:
# $emailAddresses = 
$split -replace '^', $mail -replace '$', $domain
```

This relies on `-replace` being able to operate on *arrays* as input, in which case the replacement operation is performed on *each element*, resulting in a transformed array as output.

[Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) `^` matches the start of a string, `$` matches the end, so that the two operations effectively *prepend* / *append* the value of `$mail` / `$domain`  to each element of `$split`.

Answer (score 0):

And you can user variable for pipelines in mklements0's solution:

```
$elements = $split | ForEach-Object { $mail + $_ + $domain }
# test_5@test.com
Write-Host $elements[3]
```